# footable: removeClass not working for extended row

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html-table, footable

I use footable for a mail inbox. Therefore I load the rows via AJAX and mark unread mails as bold (using an own CSS) by creating the JSON on server side.
On expanding the row I want to remove the css-class, so I use

```
.on({'expand.ft.row': function(e, ft, row){
                    row.$el.removeClass('text-bold');
                    //do sth on the server side (database update)                   
                    }               
                })
```

This works, but not for the expanded row itself! Any efforts to go down the DOM by $(row.$el).next('.footable-detail-row tr').removeClass(....) fail, because the expandend footable-detail-row does not exist yet, as the event is fired before the row is expanded.

It seems that the classes are hold somewhere in the underlying footable data or row object, but I have no idea how to access and change that...

Can you help me?

[image]

After Expansion the row is not bold except the extended column:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `expanded.ft.row`, available now according to this: https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/678